# Where does salesforce save file while uploading an attachment?

Tags: salesforce

I have created a custom code that overrides the default "Send an Email" button on Contact object. 
In case of standard button, when we select "My Computer", browse any file and click on "Attach file" button , it gets saved somewhere.

Can anyone tell me where is this file getting saved in my org ? Is there any standard object that is not visible ?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Did you find your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to share your code for a exact answer.
If you are creating a Attachment object in your code and setting the parentID to the ID of the contact, then the attached file if uploaded successfully will show up under the Notes and attachments related list.
You may not have this list on the layout, and may need to add it to the layout to see the record.